# Create and import swift framework

Tags: iphone, swift, compilation, frameworks, ios8

I'm new in swift programming.
I need to create pure swift framework and import it in my existing pure swift project.
When I try to import swift framework, I'm getting this error 
message:

```
"Could not build Objective-C module '<myModule>'"
```

[image: Framework File Structure]

**Test.h**

```
 import Foundation

public class Test {
    class func printTest() {
        println("111");
    }
}
```

**Asdf.h**

```
import UIKit
public class Asdf: Test {
    class func echo() {
        println(888);
    }
}
```

**myModule-Swift.h**

```
#ifndef <myModule>_<myModule>_Swift_h
#define <myModule>_<myModule>_Swift_h

#endif
```

After framework build, i have added framework in my existing project and get this
[image: Project Structure and import problem screen]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks For Help!

@findall comment answer -
I tried to add all framework files to my project root folder and inside project folder, but again got the same error
[image: Add Framework files to project root]

[image: Add Framework files inside project folder]

Comment: I want to know how to do perfectly that, too. But, there is a workaround about that. Not only ".framework", also add the project itself of a framework to an use-side project 's hierarchy. After this, all public symbols in the framework can be seen from the use-side.

Comment: I tried to add files (I edited the question), but again get the same error, can you explain more details?

Comment: Not files of the framework, try to add a reference to the ".xcodeproj" of the framework through `Project Navigator`.
If you want to deploy on a real device, you have to also add ".framework" to `Embedded Binaries`.

Comment: I have added .xcodeproj in my project, but the problem was not solved

Comment: Okay, please let me try to explain the things I've done in step by step as an answer.
 I'm still not good at English, so I hope I won't confuse you. (-_-;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've done with the following steps.

1. Create a framework project, for example named "FooKit". (`Cocoa Touch Framework` to be selected)
2. Create a ".swift" file and add a public symbol, for example `public func foo()`, to it.
3. Create an use-side (app) project. (I've chosen `Single View Application`)
4. Open the root directory of "FooKit" by Finder, drag "FooKit.xcodeproj" there and drop it into the app project via `Project Navigator`.
5. Add "FooKit" to `Target Dependencies` in the app's `Build Phases` setting.
6. Add "FooKit.framework" to `Embedded Binaries` in the app's `General` setting.

Now you can build like this code in the use-side app.

```
import FooKit

func bar() {
    foo()
}
```

Comment: It's working for me as well, but I wonder why we can't just drag and drop the compiled framework? What does xcworkspace do behind the scenes to make it work?

Comment: i have tha same question Mazyod

Comment: @findall, this doesn't making sense for me.
If we are going to put .xcodepoj file so what is need of Framework?
I mean no security of code?

Comment: Hi all, I have the same question as you do. I am following the below tutorial for making Framework, and adding the framework 

https://medium.com/@PyBaig/build-your-own-cocoa-touch-frameworks-in-swift-d4ea3d1f9ca3#.wftv6kglt

But when I try to import, it shows "No Such Module"

Comment: @ZaidPathan... do you still put the .xcodeproject instead of just the frameworks or is there any changes happened recently?

Comment: @Saty , I didn't see it recently but according to what I know, there is no change yet.

Comment: @ZaidPathan... so it means if I will make any code and include it in a framework, then if I will handover this to third-party, I have to give them the total code? is not it?

Comment: @Saty, In Case of Swift Yes.
But In case of Obj-C the compiled .framework or .a file will be shared.

Comment: @all...if you wish to provide framework without showing the source code.. please use cocoapod-packager.... to make a framework which works with swift /objective c... ....

Comment: you can make a cocoapod project make it work with a private repos and then package them using cocoapod-packager!!!

Comment: This does not work. The import tells me that there is no such framework as the one I added :-( Also, what's the point in adding the xcodeproj? I want a framework. Should be simple, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Saty [Develop a Swift Framework](https://medium.com/captain-ios-experts/develop-a-swift-framework-1c7fdda27bf1)

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 7.2 using Swift 2.1 I managed to get past the mentioned error by making sure that the build settings of your pure Swift framework called Foo are as follows:

1) Build Settings->Packaging->Defines Module = **Yes**

2) Build Settings->Swift Compiler - Code Generation->Install Objective-C Compatibility Header = **Yes** (if you do not need to import your Swift framework into Objective C set this setting to **No**)

3) Erase the string value of **Build Settings->Swift Compiler - Code Generation->Objective-C Bridging Header**

4)**Build Settings->Swift Compiler - Code Generation->Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name** = Foo-Swift.h (if you do not need to import your Swift framework into Objective C erase this setting as you did in step 3))

5) Make sure that **Build Settings->Packaging->Product Name = Foo**

6) Add to the **public** umbrella header of your framework (Foo.h), which you can use to import your Swift code to Objective C, the following line:

```
#import "Foo-Swift.h"
```

(but if you do not need to import your Swift code into objective C skip this step)

6) Add the following line to the Swift file where you want to use the module Foo:

```
import Foo
```

Important notes:

1) Ensure that your umbrella header Foo.h is set to public in the File Inspector, otherwise this won't work.

2) If you are using your pure Swift framework in Objective C files, ensure that:

- the Foo-Swift.h header has generated the correct interface by going to Foo.h and then clicking on the top left corner menu of the Xcode code editor and then choosing Includes->Foo-Swift.h (I had to rebuild the Foo framework a few times until Xcode caught-up with the change and then generated the correct interface in Objective C, so you may need to do that as well)
- your swift classes inherit from NSObject or they won't be available to Objective C code

Comment: This should be ranked so much higher.  I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally for @jvarela's answer, in Xcode 9 and swift 4,

To import Swift framework in an Objective C project, you must add

> @objc

mark to all of your classes, methods and variables which you want to export into Objective C project .

For example,

```
@objc public class Foo: NSObject {

    @objc public var fooDescription: String

    @objc public func foo(){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**On Swift:**

*Create Framework:-*

1. Start Xcode -> Create a new Xcode Project -> iOS -> Framework & Library -> Cocoa Touch Framework -> Name the framework(ex. sampleCocoaFramework) -> Create.
2. Set Taget -> General -> Deployment info -> Deployment Target.
3. Add a public class: File -> New File -> iOS -> Swift File -> Name it (ex. openCocoaClass) -> Create.
4. Now add some code to the openCocoaClass.swift.

   ```
   import Foundation

   public class openCocoaClass {

       public init() {

       }

       public var samplePublicVariable = "samplePublicVariable @ openCocoaClass"

       public func samplePublicFunction()
       {
           print("samplePublicFunction @ openCocoaClass")
       }
   ```

   }
5. Clean the project : Product -> Clean
6. Configure the scheme settings : Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Build Configuration -> Release.
7. Build the framework : Product -> Build.
8. Export the framework : Products -> Select the framework -> Identity and type -> Full Path -> Released Framework.

*Adding Framework to Project:-*

1. Start a Xcode project and name it (ex. CocoaFrameworkTest).
2. Drag and drop the sampleCocoaFramework.framework to the CocoaFrameworkTest's project folder.
3. Target -> General -> Embed Binaries -> Add Other -> Select Framework 
   -> Copy Items if needed -> Done.

*Accessing Framework on ViewController:*-

```
import UIKit
import sampleCocoaFramework


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let frameworkObject =  openCocoaClass.init()
        frameworkObject.samplePublicFunction()
        print(frameworkObject.samplePublicVariable)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this step In xcode 8.0 : 8.Export the framework : Products -> Select the framework -> Identity and type -> Full Path -> Released Framework.

Comment: How can I add frameworks based on architecture instead of making fat one.