# Is it necessary to include .xcodeproj file to use my Swift framework in new project?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift2

While developing a Swift framework I found that I only can use my framework after adding `.xcodeproj` file to my new project.

Here are some references I followed:
[Ref:1](https://medium.com/@PyBaig/build-your-own-cocoa-touch-frameworks-in-swift-d4ea3d1f9ca3) , [Ref:2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26482104/3411787) , [Ref:3](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-framework-creation/)

They all have did good job, but the problem is they all added their `.xcodeproj` file to their new projects which uses that framework.

My question is does it make sense?,
I mean anyone who wants to use my framework will need to use my `.xcodeproj` file?

If yes,then there is no code privacy. :-(

Or I am doing something wrong?