# Create Swift framework (revisited)

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I have read [Create and import swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460998/create-and-import-swift-framework) (and many more) but it does not work. Here's what I did: I created a vanilla framework and added a simple Test.swift.

[image]

This builds with no issues and I guess that this should be a valid framework containing my Test class.

Now I import this framework to another vanilla app:

[image]

But trying to access my framework fails:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information available from your question, "no such module" can mean that you either aren't linking against the framework, or the framework is not in the framework search path. Further, it looks like you have dragged the built framework directly into the dependent project, because I don't see the project where FW.framework included either as a top-level project in a workspace, or as a project dependency (i.e. you have not dragged FW.xcodeproj into the project navigator when you have FrameworkUse open). There are a few ways to resolve this:

1. Drag `FW.xcodeproj` into the project navigator somewhere under the `FrameworkUse` project (this will add `FW.xcodeproj` as a subproject to the `FrameworkUse` project). Then go to build settings and a) add the `FW.framework` target as a target dependency to the `FrameworkUse` target, b) add the framework (from the Products group under `FW.xcodeproj`) as an embedded binary.
2. Drag `FW.xcodeproj` to the top level in the project navigator when you have FrameworkUse project open. Xcode will ask if you want to create a new workspace (unless you already had a workspace open, at which case FW.xcodeproj will be added to the workspace). Similarly as with the above option, go to build settings and a) add the `FW.framework` target as a target dependency to the `FrameworkUse` target, b) add the framework (from the Products group under `FW.xcodeproj`) as an embedded binary.
3. If you really want to depend on the built `FW.framework` instead of expressing a build dependency to it with either option 1 or 2, you need to a) add the framework as an embedded binary, and b) go to Build Settings and add the directory containing the `FW.framework` (whose location you can find by opening it in Finder into "Framework search path", for instance `"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks"` if Frameworks under the project directory is where you place built frameworks).

Comment: I wen't with 3. It's a bit crazy that Link with Binary" shows my framework, but actually one needs to add the search path in addition. Once you know it, it's easy. But basically this is not what I call user friendly. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it's burnt me many a time too. It's especially unhelpful that the error message does not change at all from adding the linking stage in this case.

Comment: Additionally, you need to add the framework to General/Embedded Binaries or you get a "dyld: Library not loaded" error.

Comment: Yep, I did include that in my answer. Another option is to create a "Copy phase" where you place the framework under Frameworks inside the binary (this is basically what the "Embedded binary" thing, that was introduced a few Xcode versions back, does).