# How do you structure your Swift Cocoa Touch framework like Apple (e.g UIKit)

Tags: swift, frameworks

I have my own Swift Cocoa Touch framework that I use for my projects. This framework includes all sorts of different classes. For simplicity sake lets say it has 3 classes (GameCenter, In App Purchases and ReplayKit)

When you are in an actual project and you do a CMD click on an API from a framework you can see the header file of the framework with all the public methods that you can call. For my own framework I will only see 1 header file so basically all the 3 public APIs/Classes are in 1 massive list.

When you CMD click on a API from Apple, lets say `UIView`, you only get a preview of the header file for the APIs that relate to `UIViews`, not a massive list of all of the APIs for the UIKit framework.

So my question is how can I make a framework like that where I have 1 framework but each class/API within the framework has its own header file.

Do I need to create Umbrella frameworks for this? I heard this is not recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and import swift framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460998/create-and-import-swift-framework)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already know how to ad the framework.

Answer (score 0):

### you have to create a static library and then you have to convert that lib into framework. you can follow below link. https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for your answer, I will check out the link now.

Comment: Hey, Thanks again for your answer. I did actually read this Tutorial a while back. Thats basically how I made my Framework, but it does not address the issue in my question. This kind of Framework uses 1 header file as well.